# React-query: invalidateQueries doesn't work

Tags: react-query

I'm trying to invalidate queries when I create new comment.

```
const { data: comments } = useQuery("getComments", () => getComments({ originalKind: "NOTICE", originalSeq: id }));
```

```
const createCommentMutation = useMutation(postComment, {
  onSuccess: async () => {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    await queryClient.invalidateQueries("getComments");
  },
});
```

The comment is created successfully, but invalidateQueries dose not working.
There is no default options...

every time i create comment, the query will invalidated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a `new QueryClient`, it will have a new `QueryCache`,  which is not associated with the cached data of your query. That's not how it works, and that's also not what any of the official examples / docs are showing.

What you have to do is get access to the client with `useQueryClient()` - another hook exported from `react-query`. This will give you the singleton QueryClient that you have put into the `QueryClientProvider`:

```
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query'

const queryClient = useQueryClient()

const createCommentMutation = useMutation(postComment, {
  onSuccess: async () => {
    await queryClient.invalidateQueries("getComments");
  },
});
```